# What is the error while migration in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried to execute the following migration command:

```
rails g migration add_user_to_posts user_id:integer
```

but i got this error:

```
/mapper.rb:233:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :action (ArgumentError)
/mapper.rb:116:in `normalize_options!'
```

how to rectify these errors?

Comment: show your `routes.rb`.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by incorrect routes -  Please check your config/routes.rb check if any routes is defined incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are getting is related to routes.

Check your `routes.rb` and there is a mapping of controller with its action. So if it's not proper,
the error will be thrown as:

```
`default_controller_and_action': missing :action (ArgumentError)
```

**For example:**

Common mistake-

```
root :to => "home/index"
```

Correct Way-

```
root :to => "home#index"
```

Check out the post: [Default Controller and Actions](http://asheepapart.blogspot.in/2010/07/mapperrb143in-defaultcontrollerandactio.html).

As indicated,

> The error says that the default controller is missing an action.

Comment: This should be right answer. After more research I've edit my own answer and up voted this one.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The @Ved Prakash answer is correct, after more research I've found that my answer was not good enough. I'm leaving here just a relevant note for Rails 4.x

When you starting using Rails 4.x you have a new method to add references:

> rails generate migration AddUserRefToProducts user:references

Answer (score 0):

I think in your routes having problem.

make sure the

> root_path

like,

> root :to => 'home#index'

Comment: i have a root :to attribute, but when i comment it out, it seems to show no error. Do you think the error is due to this?